# Products regularly not showing up but reindex

Tags: magento2.4, reindex, index

I'm new on setting up Magento.
I'm currently on 2.4.6-p2, which I had imported a list of products by csv.

Previously on the Index Management I was using "Update on Save" which the product can load properly in the frontend at that moment,
But after a day, I can see most of the products are not longer showing in the frontend (including most of the filtering attribute). It will work after using Terminal to reindex the indexer.

I tried to change the Index Management to "Update by Schedule" and set it as 10 mins interval but the problem remains. (I can see the Index Management functions properly and updated according to the schedule)

Is there any settings I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: I still need to manually reindex daily to showing the 200 items or only 8 showing up... even the index management shows it was doing the indexing already

Comment: All indexes are "Update by Schedule" Currently the cron job command is as follow run every 10 mins: /opt/alt/php81/usr/bin/php /home/xxx/public_html/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/xxx/public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset your indexer using below command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

and then reindex again.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Check your problem is solved or not.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried this see if tomorrow the products listing can stay showing normally. Will keep an update on this

Comment: This morning, the same things happens again

Comment: Please check if your cron job is working correctly also the indexing of products are on schedule or save ?

Comment: Tried both method but the problem remains. I've found in the debug.log there's some warning message, not sure if related to the issue
main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: bulk_cleanup [] []
main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: catalog_product_frontend_actions_flush [] []
main.WARNING: Could not acquire lock for cron job: catalog_product_outdated_price_values_cleanup [] []